# Example of Janrain RPX authentication in JS?

Tags: javascript, rpxnow

I would like to integrate janrain to a website. For a reason, server-side I can only use standard javascript.

I have already installed the widget and I am now trying to do the authentication part. I went through the documentation and code-samples, but I can't find one sample only in JS. And I not skilled enough in JS to do it myself.

( https://github.com/janrain/Janrain-Sample-Code )

Has anyone already implemented it only in JS without any php or anything else on the server-side and could give me a sample working code ?

Thanks.